# product between a scalar and a vector, is it really defined?

Tags: vector-spaces

When defining a vector space (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition)
we define the distributivity of a scalar but not its commutativity.
It gives me the impression that, for a, a scalar, and v, a vector.

a . v is defined, but not v . a.

I had never encountered v . a until today in my course, so I found it very strange. Is that really ok?

Comment: Scalars are confined to a field, so their addition and multiplication both commute and associate.

Comment: I think you are right that v.a is not defined. But if it needs a definition (and I'm not sure that it does) then it is natural and obvious to define it as being equal to a.v.

Answer (score 1):

To better understand what is going on with the notation $a \cdot v$, you should first understand what are "operations". Very vaguely, operations are functions that take input from a certain number of sets and give output in another set. For instance, if we look at the operation "addition" in the case of real numbers, we should ask:

1. What do we require to make sense of "addition"?
2. What output do we get when we add two numbers?

The answer to the first question is indeed two real numbers. And the answer to the second one is again, a real number! Also, notice that the addition of two numbers cannot give two different outputs.

So, basically, we have a function which we denote as $+: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. And instead of writing $+ \left( a, b \right)$, we write $a + b$ to denote the value of $+$ at the pair $\left( a, b \right)$.

In this way, you can see many operations as functions, and in particular coming to your vector space question, you can also see the vector addition as a function $+: V \times V \rightarrow V$.

Now, let us talk about scalar multiplication, which you want to understand. To "scale" a vector what do we require? Indeed, a vector (that needs to be scaled) and a scalar (which will scale the vector). After scaling what output will we get? A vector! Can we get two different vectors if we scale a single vector with a single scalar? No!

So, scalar multiplication is a function which takes a scalar (element from the field) and a vector (an element from a given set) and gives output a vector. That is, we want $\cdot: \mathbb{F} \times V \rightarrow V$. Again, only for notational purposes, instead of writing $\cdot \left( a, v \right)$ to denote the value of $\cdot$ at the pair $\left( a, v \right)$, we write $a \cot v$.

Now, one may ask why only should we take $\cdot: \mathbb{F} \times V \rightarrow V$ and not $\cdot: V \times \mathbb{F} \rightarrow V$? For the latter does give us the notation $v \cdot a$ in place of $\cdot \left( v, a \right)$. However, this is only about writing such a thing! It is widely accepted that the "first" input of scalar multiplication should be a scalar and the second one be a vector. This is the reason almost every book uses the notation that you have seen instead of the other one.

I hope this does clear a few things about writing notations, and operations. If you are more interested, you can look at some basic algebra textbooks, which give a nice detailed description of operations.

Comment: Thanks for the big answer. I understand your point, but your reasoning implicitly allows "operators" to commute each member without changing the result. To evade that problem, you mention the following "can we get two different vectors if we scale a single vector with a single scalar", as though it must be obvious. But I'll give you a really obvious example that two objects, with a given operator, by commuting the two will no give the same result : multiplication between matrices! Even though an uneducated guess would be it would give the game result!

Comment: It's not just a question of "writing about it", it's a matter of definition. Implicitness should be banned in mathematics, that is my belief. What is not said, is not a thing.

Comment: The notion of "commutativity" is very special for operations defined on the same set (specifically, they are called binary operations). Yes, matrices do not commute in general, but also notice that whether you write $A \cdot B$ or $B \cdot A$, the result is always a single matrix. What I meant by the sentence you quote is that if you take a pair, it will give you one and only one output (I wanted to bring out the definition of a function). It has got nothing to do with commutativity of the operator itself.

Comment: There isn't any inplicitness. And it is not only a matter of writing as well. As I have said in the answer, we define $\cdot$ to be a function from $\mathbb{F} \times V$ to $V$. So, the "first" input must be a scalar to make sense. It is not wrong to define it from $V \times \mathbb{F}$ to $V$. In that case, the scalar will be the "second" input. Only thing is that the first notation is widely accepted.

Comment: It is a recursive problem, because it assumes that × between two sets is commutative. I did not know.

Comment: Additionnally, while we can agree that the nature of the ouput object is always the same, regardless of commutativity. The value is not necessarily the same, because well, as you said commutativity is not trivial between two objects of the same sets, but what has it to say that it should be trivial for two objects of differents sets?

Comment: But I'll leave it at a problem of notation, even though I find it not very rigorous. Thank you.

Comment: That is because if the sets are different, there is *no* commutativity. You only have to *define* the other thing. And the natural thing to do is to define it the same. Which is why I have specifically written *define* at several places instead of commutativity.

Comment: You're right, commutativity is only defined for two objects of the same set. In case of different sets it's another question.  I didn't know.